# Programmatically creating a scrollable drop-down menu (iOS/Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, drop-down-menu, uiscrollview, swift3

When the "Colors" `navigation bar button` is clicked, a drop-down menu of 15 colors should appear. The drop-down will take up half of the screen's height and width. The user can scroll down the drop-down to view all the colors. However, the code I have right now, nothing happens when the navigation bar button is clicked. Although for testing purposes, when I set the background color of the scroll view to something more visible, I see that the scroll view is taking up half the screen's width and height. And when I add `view.addSubview(colorView)` at the end of `colorButtonTapped()` I see the drop-down display is taking up half of the screen's width and all of the screen's height.

```
AppDelegate:
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)

        window?.rootViewController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: ViewController())
        window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
        return true
    }
```

---

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {
    var colorView: UIView!
    var scrollView: UIScrollView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        colorView = UIView()
        scrollView = UIScrollView()

        let colorButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Colors", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(colorButtonTapped))
        colorButton.setTitleTextAttributes([NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14.0), NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.black], for: UIControlState())
        navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.rightBarButtonItem = colorButton
    }

    func colorButtonTapped() {
        let colorOptions = ["Blue", "Black", "Red", "Green", "Yellow", "Purple", "Orange", "Pink", "Magenta", "Lavender", "Beige", "Tan", "Burgundy", "Eggshell", "Brown"]
        let buttonHeight: CGFloat = UIScreen.main.bounds.height / 15

        colorView.layer.cornerRadius = 8
        colorView.clipsToBounds = true

        //create options button
        for (index, title) in colorOptions.enumerated() {
            let button = UIButton(type: .custom)
            button.backgroundColor = .red

            button.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: buttonHeight * CGFloat(index), width: colorView.frame.width, height: buttonHeight)
            button.setTitle(title, for: .normal)
            colorView.addSubview(button)
        }

        scrollView.delegate = self
        scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 2.0, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height / 2.0)
        scrollView.addSubview(colorView)
        view.addSubview(scrollView)
    }

    override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()
        let y = (navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.height)! + UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.height
    scrollView.frame = CGRect(x: UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 2.0, y: y, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 2.0, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height / 2.0)
    colorView.frame = CGRect(x: UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 2.0, y: y, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 2.0, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no point to update the frames of `scrollView` and `colorView` every time `viewWillLayoutSubviews` is called. It is enough to create upon pressing the button.

The code below would set the frame of `colorView`'s `x` and `y` exactly to the right edge of `scrollView`, therefore it is *not visible*. Both should be `0` to position it to the left edge.

```
 colorView.frame = CGRect(x: UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 2.0, y: y, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 2.0, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height)
```

The last is the `colorView`'s `isUserInteractionEnabled` property. By default it is enabled, therefore it swallows the gesture recogniser from `scrollView`. Set it to `false`, and [enjoy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dVeM5.gif).

To overcome on problems like this in the future, i would recommend to read more about [view debugging](https://www.raywenderlich.com/98356/view-debugging-in-xcode-6).

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {

    var colorView: UIView!
    var scrollView: UIScrollView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        colorView = UIView()
        scrollView = UIScrollView()

        let colorButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Colors", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(colorButtonTapped))
        colorButton.setTitleTextAttributes([NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14.0), NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.black], for: UIControlState())
        navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.rightBarButtonItem = colorButton
    }

    func colorButtonTapped() {

        let colorOptions = ["Blue", "Black", "Red", "Green", "Yellow", "Purple", "Orange", "Pink", "Magenta", "Lavender", "Beige", "Tan", "Burgundy", "Eggshell", "Brown"]

        let y = (navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.height)! + UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.height
        scrollView.frame = CGRect(x: UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 2.0, y: y, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 2.0, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height / 2.0)
        scrollView.delegate = self
        scrollView.isScrollEnabled = true

        let buttonHeight: CGFloat = UIScreen.main.bounds.height / 15
        let contentHeight: CGFloat = CGFloat(colorOptions.count) * buttonHeight
        colorView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: scrollView.frame.width, height: contentHeight)
        colorView.layer.cornerRadius = 8
        colorView.clipsToBounds = true
        colorView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false

        scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 2.0, height: contentHeight)

        for (index, title) in colorOptions.enumerated() {
            let button = UIButton(type: .custom)
            button.backgroundColor = .red
            button.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: buttonHeight * CGFloat(index), width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 2.0, height: buttonHeight)
            button.setTitle(title, for: .normal)
            colorView.addSubview(button)
        }

        scrollView.addSubview(colorView)
        view.addSubview(scrollView)
    }
}
```

Comment: It works pretty well but  button.addTarget is not work..pls

Comment: What do you mean by `addTarget` ?

Comment: dropDownView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true do that for work addTarget  make ture  .isUserInteractionEnabled  in the code